# C++ regular expression

Tags: c++, regex, cgi

I need to capture data from a variable using a regular expression. The data are available on the form:  `Ip=8.8.8.8&probe=ip/tcp{dst=53}` 
for example.

To achieve this I`m using:

```
char *data;
data = getenv("QUERY_STRING");
char ipt[40];
char probe[40]; 
sscanf(data,"ip=%[0-9a-zA-Z-.]&probe=%[0-9a-zA-Z-.{}/=]",ipt,probe);
```

The second field will always contain a / but I can't get this and the other special carachters ({}=)

What can I do?

I already tried:

```
sscanf(data,"ip=%[0-9a-zA-Z-.]&probe=%[(...)]",ipt,probe);
```

And had no success as well.

Comment: Which resource had let got  you inoculated that `sscanf()` supports regular expressions?

Comment: As Jerry Coffin said, sscanf do not support full regular expressions, but they do support scansets!

Comment: Update: For the IP field, there's no problem at all, it is working the way I posted. The IP field always receive an IP address or a webpage (e.g www.google.com). The probe field can vary, so it will not always end with an } it can be, for example TCP/IP or IP/tcp{dst=53} etc. Now I understand what the problem is. I'm receiving data from a web browser and the symbols ({}/=) are encoded (such as %7B %7D %3D) Now I need to find a way for my software to identify %7B %7D %3D as {}= for example. Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you know the `probe` part ends with `}` and the IP part end with a `&`, it's probably easiest to just scan for those:

```
sscanf(input, "Ip=%[^&]&probe=%[^}]", ipt, probe);
```

One minor detail: `scanf` with either a scanset or a %s conversion *needs* to have the buffer size specified to have any safety at all. without a length, both are pretty much equivalent to `gets` for lack of safety, so you really want something like:

```
char ipt[256], probe[256];
sscanf(input, "Ip=%255[^&]&probe=%255[^}]", ipt, probe);
```

Also note that this will give you the `probe` part *without* the trailing `}`. If you really need it, you can use something like `strncat` to add it back on afterwards though.

For those looking on: no, scanf (and company) don't support full regular expressions, but they do support scansets, which is what he's using here.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. For the IP field, there's no problem at all, it is working the way I posted. The IP field always receive an IP address or a webpage (e.g www.google.com). The probe field can vary, so it will not always end with an } it can be, for example TCP/IP or IP/tcp{dst=53} etc. But what you said helped to understand what the problem is. I`m receiving data from a web browser and the symbols ({}/=) are encoded (such as %7B %7D %3D) Now I need to find a way for my software to identify %7B %7D %3D as {}= for example. Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user2375607: The obvious way would be to run the data through a decoder to turn those encoded sequences back into the target characters before trying to parse/search it.